# Creating Login Page Using C#/SQL Window Application .

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ado.net

> i've been working with C# Application and i want to create login page for it
>   but i face a problem with this code , it seemed to be not working

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataReader sdr;
        string query = "select * from User where User_Name = '" + textBox1.Text + "'and User_Password = '" + this.textBox2.Text + "'";
        SqlConnection connectpassword = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=AHMEDIBRAHIM\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Payment;Integrated Security=True");
        connectpassword.Open();
        SqlCommand logincomand = new SqlCommand( query, connectpassword);
        logincomand.Parameters.Add(@"n", SqlDbType.Text).Value = textBox1.Text;
        logincomand.Parameters.Add(@"p", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox2.Text;
        sdr = logincomand.ExecuteReader();
        int i = 0; 
       while (sdr.Read()){

           i = i + 1; 

       }
       if (i == 1) { 

            MessageBox.Show("User Name and Password incroect ");


           }
       else if (i > 1)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Duplicate username and password", "login page");
       }
       else
       {
           MessageBox.Show(" username and password incorrect", "login page");
       }
```

> Once i rung it ! .. i get this  `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely having issues because "User" is a keyword in Sql Server.  You can fix it by changing it to:

```
string query = "select * from [User] where User_Name = '" + textBox1.Text + "'and User_Password = '" + this.textBox2.Text + "'";
```

Comment: >i change it but i still get this error `  The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator `

Comment: `  The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator `

Comment: your first parameter, "n"... change the SqlDbType to SqlDbType.VarChar

Comment: its type in DB is Text not varchar ! @oppassum

Comment: should i change it to varchar ?

Comment: It's worth a try... you know what the issue is by this point, just figure out how your data types are different

Comment: oh, you aren't doing this correctly.  those parameters aren't even being used

Comment: i'm sorry , but it's not working ! , and i don't not how to solve it ! , can to tell me brief and i will be thankful

Comment: I'm sorry but you need a better understanding of what you're doing.  here's another stackoverflow to help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/using-parameters-in-sql-statements   and here's the MSDN for SqlCommand https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx